# Receiving content from ASP.NET page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, viewstate

When I made an AJAX call to an ASP.NET page, I had a mechanism to return some text based on QueryString parameters. Such as :

```
Response.Write("<text>");
```

But in the response, I got a lot of extra information about viewstate status. This does not happen in classic ASP or PHP. Also if I ask for the whole page, it returns it with the page directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Isn't it a bad idea on the part of ASP.NET to give away the information about backend implementation (.cs) ? How to avoid this extra information and pass only the required one?

Currently I am using PHP page for returning things for the same purpose. It works totally fine.

Comment: You probably have an error in your IIS configuration. Page directives are never returned to the client. Also, it will be better to use WCF or a classic ASHX service for AJAX requests.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET AJAX or Core AJAX?

Comment: Well then I recommend you to use ASP.NET AJAX, and believe that it would probably solve your problem... Hint: Use UpdatePanel..

Comment: So there's no solution to use AJAX with ASP.NET? One way I found was the character count framing. I start the string with response length followed by a special character. At client side, I write a small middleware function to extract the exact response

Comment: But I find this a compromise as others like PHP don't make me do this.

Comment: @Mahendra: ASP.NET AJAX is slow and uses a lot of overhead in the request and response, especially an UpdatePanel. Have a look at alternative solutions, like Gaia AJAX (gaiaware.net)

Comment: @KBoek completely agreed. I'd prefer not to use ASP.NET than to use ASP.NET AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest brute-force way to get around this issue is to make your Web service a generic handler (.ashx) instead of an .aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Response.Write with AJAX calls, but rather update a control ie. set a Label's Text property. Can you tell more about which functionality you want? We might be able to give you an alternative solution.

Which AJAX implementation are you using (Microsoft's, or a third party) ?

[Help me understand web methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525313/help-me-understand-web-methods)

http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2009/03/jquery-json-and-asmx-20-services.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/jsonwebservice.aspx

Comment: I am using the raw AJAX. And consider any functionality. For example I want to recieve a JSON object from another code-page.

Comment: There's no problem in using raw AJAX (I assume you mean that you use the XmlHttp object to call the server), but instead of calling a method that returns a void, you should call a method that returns a string. The string you return can be picked up by the XmlHttp object.

Comment: @KBoek sorry but I didn't get it. I can not call any server side method directly with XmlHttp. I have to call the page with querystring. The code in the page then has to decide what to return. I that case, how can XmlHttp pick up something 'returned' (under a C# wrapper) by a function??

Comment: Ah, so you're actually just calling another page using the XmlHttp object? That's definitely not the ideal way. If you want to implement AJAX yourself, then you should understand and use web methods, or asynchronous handlers. If you don't have experience with that, the simplest is to use an AJAX library from a third party. But it's rather interesting to learn it if you have time and will.

Comment: I did a Google for "xmlhttprequest asp.net httphandler" and found some links that I copied into my original message (see above). You can aslo Google yourself and find a lot of interesting information.

Comment: Thank you so much sir and sorry for my illiteracy :) I am shifting from ASP and PHP to ASP.NET and am somewhat unaware but sure not ignorant. I will learn this feature asap.

Comment: You're welcome :) glad I could help, that's what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use ASP.NET AJAX with ASP.NET, rather than raw AJAX (core AJAX). Use UpdatePanel control to make dynamic updates.

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a configuration issue. Try running the page with query strings alone without AJAX calls.

Such executed aspx page (Without HTML) should return the text you seek with no "viewstate status". Plus it never returns the page directive if it was well executed.